# Garmin connect in C# application

Tags: c#, api, garmin

I'm having C# MVC website and want to display current Garmin data (eg: activity) on my home page. For that I need to get my user to Garmin's login page and after successful login I want user to be redirected to Website's home page. I've searched a lot for this but didn't get any proper API document as we have for other tracking devices like Withings or Fitbit.

Found below document related to authentication process:
https://developer.garmin.com/index.php/blog/post/connect-iq-2-authentication

Is Garmin API paid? as shown in below document:
https://developer.garmin.com/garmin-connect-api/overview/

How can I make API calls to fetch Activity, Steps, Sleep data from Garmin?

Can anyone please suggest me a right path to achieve what I mentioned above.

Comment: API is paid, $5000 one time fee. After you pay that fee, you'll get client ID and secret key that allow you login to your connect acount.

Comment: @Nino will then I be able to make API calls and fetch data. One more doubt: is it going to be free for lifetime once I pay fee?

Comment: I can't say. Probably it will. But, first of all, I suggest you learn a thing or two about OAuth and try to use some public and well documented API like Twitter's. Then, when you get to know how to connect and how to call certain methods, consider buying Connect API

Comment: I did use Oauth for Fitbit API call but It was having a well descriptive document so it was quite easy to use it. Can you plz tell me the authentication url of Garmin? Or Is there any Open source way to make an API call?

Comment: sorry, can't help you there. Because it is commercial API, you'll get nowhere without paying the fee. Or, try contacting Garmin for assistance.

Comment: Ok. No worries. Thanks for the help.